# for loop : Cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I was wondering why I had this error when I tried to do this :

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = (Map<Integer, List<String>>) parameters;

for(Integer i : map.keySet()) {
    tableFiles.setWidget(row, 0, addPanelFile(String.valueOf(i)));
    row++;
    for(map.get(i)) {

    }
}
```

Why can't i be resolved to a variable ?

Comment: The easiest and most efficient way to iterate through a map if you need both the key and value is to iterate through the `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>` returned by `entrySet()`.  Then you don't need to do a get, you already have the value in the `Entry`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The for-loop is malformed.

Change

```
for(((Map<Integer, List<String>>) parameters).get(i)) {

}
```

into

```
for(SomeType someVar : ((Map<Integer, List<String>>) parameters).get(i)) {

}
```

and you should get a better error-message.

Comment: @Mark Peters : well, that's a typo. Edited

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm a bit tired, should have seen this

Answer (score 0):

Something of this effect. `foreach` uses `Iterator` for iterations;

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = (Map<Integer, List<String>>) parameters;

for (Integer i : map.keySet()) {
    tableFiles.setWidget(row, 0, addPanelFile(String.valueOf(i)));
        row++;
    for (String s: map.get(i)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to expose the iterator, `keySet().iterator()` does not return an `Iterator<Iterator>`, an `Iterator` is not an `Iterable`, and you want `map` not `parameters` in the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm a bit tired, should have seen this

Comment: @Mark Peters, thanks, but `Map.get()` returns a `List<String>`. Check the OP's edited question.

Comment: Elite: I know what that returns.  I was talking about your use of `keyIter`, which is just wrong since `keyIter` is not an `Iterable`.  Just use `for (Integer i : map.keySet()) `, which actually works and doesn't unnecessarily expose the Iterator.  On the inner loop, it will fail because presumably `parameters` isn't declared as a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` or else the cast to `map` wouldn't be needed.